# How to update child list in entity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

These are models:

```
public class Contact
{
    public Contact() 
    {
        Emails = new List<Email>(); 
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Email> Emails { get; set; }

}
 public  class Email
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual int ContactId { get; set; }
}
```

On my details page user is able to add more emails, delete exsting...etc...or change existing one.
How to update collection?
I tries this:

```
    var contactFromDb = db.Contacts.Include("Emails").Include("Telephones").Where(x => x.Id == contact.Id).FirstOrDefault();

      contactFromDb.Address = contact.Address;
      contactFromDb.Name = contact.Name;
      contactFromDb.Surname = contact.Surname;
      contactFromDb.Telephones = contact.Telephones;
      contactFromDb.Emails = contact.Emails;
```

String properties are updated nicely, I tried updating collection the same way, but I get duplicate values. How to update emails?

Comment: well you need to compare the collection, which ones are new entities, then add them, which ones deleted entities then remove them, and which one existing entities then update them

Comment: in you email class contactid property shouldn't be virtual.  it should be marked by foreign key attribute and added virtual property with class contact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First delete removed emails:

```
var contactFromDb = db.Contacts.Include("Emails").Include("Telephones").FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == updatedContact.Id);
contactFromDb.Address = updatedContact.Address;
contactFromDb.Name = updatedContact.Name;
contactFromDb.Surname = updatedContact.Surname;

// Delete removed emails
var emailsToDelete = (from email in contactFromDb.Emails
                        let item = updatedContact.Emails.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == email.Id)
                        where item == null
                        select email).ToList();
if (emailsToDelete.Any())
{
    foreach (var email in emailsToDelete)
    {
        db.Entry(email).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }
}
```

After that update edited emails:

```
foreach (var email in updatedContact.Emails)
{
    // If id of an email is not equal to 0, it's not new email and it should be updated
    if (email.Id > 0)
    {
        var emailInDb = contactFromDb.Emails.Single(e => e.Id == email.Id);
        db.Entry(emailInDb).CurrentValues.SetValues(email);
        db.Entry(emailInDb).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

And finally by calling `db.SaveChanges()` new emails with Id of `0` Will be inserted and you can repeat this cycle for `Phones`.

Comment: and if email is zero,I should add email to database. It seems working, but is there more elegant solution. I have to repeat this for telephones, and other collections. It is not elegant at all.

Comment: In disconnected environment I think there is no more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

For child entites - easiest way is to delete them all and add new.

```
var contactFromDb = db.Contacts.Include("Emails").Include("Telephones").Where(x => x.Id == contact.Id).FirstOrDefault();

contactFromDb.Address = contact.Address;
contactFromDb.Name = contact.Name;
contactFromDb.Surname = contact.Surname;
contactFromDb.Telephones = contact.Telephones;
db.Entry(contactFromDb).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
foreach(Email email in contactFromDb.Emails)
{
    db.Entry(email).State = System.Data.EntityState.Deleted;
}
contactFromDb.Emails.AddRange(contact.Emails);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this generic sub to mark the child state, easy to use

> ### Notes:
>
> - PromatCon: the entity object
> - amList: is the child list that you want to add or modify
> - rList: is the child list that you want to remove

```
updatechild(objCas.ECC_Decision, PromatCon.ECC_Decision.Where(c => c.rid == objCas.rid & !objCas.ECC_Decision.Select(x => x.dcid).Contains(c.dcid)).toList())
```

```
public void updatechild<Ety>(ICollection<Ety> amList, ICollection<Ety> rList)
{
    if (amList != null)
    {
        foreach (var obj in amList)
        {
            var x = PromatCon.Entry(obj).GetDatabaseValues();
            if (x == null)
                PromatCon.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Added;
            else
                PromatCon.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }

    if (rList != null)
    {
        foreach (var obj in rList.ToList())
            PromatCon.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }
}
```

```
PromatCon.SaveChanges()
```