# Update foreign keys in an n:n relationship - Entity Framework Code First Migrations

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using Entity Framework code first migrations. There is an n:n relationship between `Profile` and `Languages` (A `Profile` can have many `Languages`). I was wondering how I can update the list of languages for the profile if I have the  language IDs (foreign key). For a 1:1 relationship (i.e. if Profile could only have 1 Language), I could just update LanguageID but for n:n I don't have a list of LanguageIDs to update so it means I have to make an extra trip to the database to retrieve the languages and initialize the Language property of the profile object. Is there any way to get around that?

Comment: "I don't have a list of LanguageIDs", why not? What's stopping you have a `virtual List<Language> Languages` on your `Profile`? You can then just clear that list and add the Languages and EF should tidy up if you have everything in context.

Comment: I don't have the languages though when I'm updating the entity. I have a list of language IDs (ints). I could go to the DB and get the Languages and initialize the Language property in the profile object with that list like you mentioned but it seems like an unnecessary hit to the DB.

Comment: You can do the updates with just the IDs. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee794150(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @SteveGreene I wasn't able to find an n:n relationship in the link you posted. In this case a grade is associated with one Student so you can just update StudentID but let's say Grade had a list of Students (n:n)?

Comment: Just loop through them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25831959/how-to-update-child-list-in-entity-framework

Comment: @SteveGreene In the case you sent me, he has a list of Emails. I don't have a list of entities. I have a list of IDs. I could get the list of entities but it seems like an extra hit to the DB that isn't needed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you titled this migrations I'll assume you want to do some sort of Seeding? I'll start with this answer so we have some code to discuss:

```
protected override void Seed(ApplicationContext context)
{
    var languageIds = new List<int> {1,2,3,4};  // FK to language. Are you assigning same list to all profiles?

    var profiles = context.Profiles.Include(p => p.Languages).ToList();
    foreach (var profile in profiles)
    {
        // Since you mention updating, you may need to remove old languages
        if (profiles.Languages.Any())
        { delete children... }

        // add new languages. You could add a test so you only seed when no languages are present
        foreach (var languageId in LanguageIds)
        {
            profile.Add(new Language {LanguageId = languageId};
        }
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know you could set a language with just a language ID and entity framework would know to update.